# Operation sequence

Tags: operator-precedence

I am new to programming and wanted to understand more on operator associativity and precedence.

```
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;
int main() {

```
int a=5;
cout << a + a++ + 1 ;
return 0;
```

}

For the above prog , the output returned is 12

Question 1)

a++ is evaluated first, followed by a and 1 , i.e; a++ + a + 1 as per precedence which becomes
5 + 6 + 1 = 12  , is this correct ??

Question 2)

But, when I write like this;

```
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;
int main() {

```
int a=5;
cout << (a) + a++ + 1 ;
return 0;
```

}

the answer is still 12 ( brackets should override precedence)
I expected the output to be :  5 + 5 + 1  = 11

Would like to know the sequence of steps here.